# Struggling to animate an image in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've started coding a Connect 4 game (a click triggers a disc to fall) and I wanted to animate the discs' fall.
So I start by creating a new disc image :

```
discList[y][x] = can.create_image((xCan,yCurrent), image=imgRedDisc, anchor="nw")
```

The disc is created at the top of the canvas at xCan; yCurrent. What I want to do now is to animate the disc falling to its destination, yCan. I call my drop function which keeps incrementing the disc's yCurrent until it reaches yCan with recursivity and the after() method :

```
def drop(disc):
    global yCan, yCurrent
    can.move(disc, 0, 1)
    yCurrent += 1
    if yCurrent < yCan:
        can.after(5, drop(disc))
```

Now what my problem is is that the disc's intermediary positions don't display, it only shows up directly at the bottom after a few seconds.
After some research I added a line to update the canvas :

```
def drop(disc):
    global yCan, yCurrent
    can.move(disc, 0, 1)
    yCurrent += 1
    can.update()
    if yCurrent < yCan:
        can.after(5, drop(disc))
```

Now I get to see my disc falling, but it gets laggy after each play ; the discs only start falling a few seconds after I've clicked (which triggers their fall). Another problem is that if I trigger two discs to fall almost silmutaneously by double-clicking very quickly, the first one stops its fall midway then simply falls out of the canvas.

My question is, how do I display every step of my discs' fall without `can.update()` ?
Also I store each disc id in a list (discList), is there a more convenient way to store dynamically created canvas images ?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do animation in tkinter is to have a function that does one frame of animation, and then have it call itself repeatedly until some terminal condition.

For example:

```
def move_object(obj_id):
    can.move(obj_id, 0, 1)
    x0,y0,x1,y1 = can.coords(obj_id)
    if y0 < yCan: 
        can.after(5, move_obj, obj_id)
```

The main difference to what you wrote is that you were using `after` incorrectly. You were doing this:

```
can.after(5, drop(disc))
```

... which is exactly the same as this:

```
result = drop(disc)
can.after(5, drop)
```

Notice the difference? Like with the `command` attribute, you must supply a *reference* to a function. You however were *calling* the function and then giving the result to `after`.

Here's a very simple example to experiment with:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

ball = canvas.create_oval(50,0,100,50, fill="red")

def animate(obj_id):
    canvas.move(obj_id, 0, 3)
    x0,y0,x1,y1 = canvas.coords(obj_id)
    if y0 > canvas.winfo_height():
        canvas.coords(obj_id, 50,-50, 100, 0)
    canvas.after(50, animate, obj_id)

animate(ball)
root.mainloop()
```